# Для чего нужен input с type="hidden"?

Tags: html

Совсем простенький вопрос, но все же для чего нужен input с type="hidden"?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Иногда на сервер нужно передать данные, которые сервер сам и сгенерировал. Если понять то, что каждый запрос к веб серверу - это независимый запрос, то серверной части нужно оставлять какие то метки для себя. Можете относиться к этому, как к своеобразным кукисам.

Comment: Да, к примеру, всякие токены для безопасности запросов (защита от CSRF).

Answer (score 5):

Скрытое поле, которое может являться системным, пользователь его не видит, но серверу его передать надо.